# How to count the number of matrix multiplications used in a function?

Tags: matlab

I'm working on a code about the Gaussian Elimination, and one of the requirements is to count the number of matrix additions and the number of matrix multiplications used in the function.  If I cannot use the "profile" command, then what should I have in my code as a counter ?

Does Matlab have some kinds of build-in function to count the number of matrix additions/multiplications used in a function ?

Thank you.

Comment: Why can't you use the profiler?

Answer (score 0):

No, not any more. It used to have a *flops* function that counted the floating number operations in your code, but this was removed many years ago. For the reason why *flops* is obsolete you can read [this](http://www.stat.uchicago.edu/~lekheng/courses/302/flops/vmdd.html).

Are you sure you need Matlab to do this? If you code is not that complex you can give a good upper estimate by calculating the number of operations by hand.

Answer (score 0):

Create a wrapper functions for the operations you need to count, and make those keep the count. Expect lots of overhead ;)
Add some logic to reset and/or show resulting count.

eg for multiplication:

```
function c = mytimes(a,b)
    persistent count;

    if nargin==1
        switch a
        case 'reset'
            c = count;
            count = 0;
        case 'show'
            c = count;
        otherwise
            error('wrong input');
        end
    end

    c = a*b;

    if isempty(count)
        count = 1;
    else
        count = count+1;
    end
end
```